# I still cant under stand how to use virualenv or wirtualenvwrapper in vscode

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am currently trying to learn django framework, and I am stuck because of the virtual environment setup in vscode, I know how to create a virtual environment and how to activate it in the terminal and how to install packages inside of it , but my problem is that I cant know if I am using it correctly , and where it should be, for example : which directory should the virtual environment be at when working on a project , should it be with that project at the same directory or what? and also I do not know how to set it up in vscode , so please guys help me with that and give me step by step how I can set the virtual environment in vscode , and in which directory should it be , I am so confused and blocked at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual environment can be anywhere. You just have to select the path to it's python interpreter while setting the project interpreter in vscode.

Refer this - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments